# How to set path for vim config files?

Tags: ruby, vim

I know they say to store your vim config files under source control.

Is there a way to tell vim where the config files are? like .vimrc etc.?

i.e. I will store them in a different folder where my other git repos are.

BTW, what are good coloring plugins for ruby?

Comment: You are asking two separate questions. Please split them up into one for the vim question, and another for Ruby plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `VIM` environment variable to change the location of your `~/.vim/` directory, if you want to keep all your git repos in one place. See the `:help $VIM` section for more details, but here's the bit that looks most useful:

```
The environment variable "$VIM" is used to locate various user files for Vim,
such as the user startup script ".vimrc".  This depends on the system, see
|startup|.
```

If you add `export VIM=/home/blankman/git/vim/` to your `~/.bashrc`, you ought to be set.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the `vim` `man` page:

```
-u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations.
               All the other initializations are  skipped.
```

To have it work whenever you run vim, try putting in your shell's startup script (.bashrc etc):

```
alias vim='vim -u /path/to/vimrc'
```

Link: http://www.h3rald.com/articles/herald-vim-color-scheme/

Has a few schemes with ruby highlighting examples. Vim has decent native ruby support it seems, so you may just want a new colour scheme.

A light-coloured Ruby highlighting scheme [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3398).